# How to write strings and numeric values into a file

Tags: c, file

The below code allows a user (through a switch-case) to select between two options: calculating some values of a square or some values of a circle. I am using this code to practice how I can write on a file the results. So far, it is writing numeric values (i.e. option chosen, square's side entered, etc.), but I would like to write offering a bit more context within the file. Example:

```
You have chosen option 1
The side of the square is 2
The square area is 4
The square perimeter is 8

Thank you!
```

My question is whether I should have two functions that write into the file: one for strings and one for numeric values, or there should be a better way of doing it with less code. Also, any suggestions to improve the current code are much appreciated! Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define PI 3.14
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

int square_functions (int side, int *area_square, int *perimeter);
float circle_functions (float radius, float * area_circle, float * circumference);
int write_on_file (int value);

int main() 
{ 

    float radius, area_circle, circumference;
    int side, area_square, perimeter,choice;
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");

    while (1) 
    {
    printf("\nPress 1 to calculate the square\n"); 
    printf("Press 2 to calculate the circumference\n");
    printf("Enter your choice:\n"); 
    scanf("%d",&choice);

    write_on_file (choice);

    switch (choice) 
        { 
        case 1: 
            printf("Please enter the side of the square: ");
            scanf("%d", &side);
            write_on_file (side);
            if(side > 0)
            {
                square_functions (side, &area_square, &perimeter);
                printf("\nSquare area: %d", area_square);
                printf("\nSquare perimeter: %d\n", perimeter);   
            }
            else
            {
                printf("The value is invalid; the operation has been canceled");
            } 
        break;

        case 2: 
            printf("\n\nPlease enter the radius of the circle: ");
            scanf("%f", &radius);

            if(radius > 0)
            {
                circle_functions (radius, &area_circle, &circumference);       
                printf("\nCircle area: %f", area_circle);
                printf("\nCircumference: %f", circumference);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("The value is invalid; the operation has been canceled");
            }
        break;
        }
    }
return 0;
}

int square_functions (int side, int * area_square, int * perimeter) 
{
        * area_square = side * side;
        * perimeter = side * 4;   
        write_on_file (*area_square);
        write_on_file (*perimeter);
        return 0;
}

float circle_functions (float radius, float * area_circle, float * circumference) 
{
        * area_circle = PI * radius * radius;
        * circumference = 2 * PI * radius;
        write_on_file (*area_circle);
        write_on_file (*circumference);
        return 0;       
}

int write_on_file (int value) 
{
        FILE * fich;
        fich=fopen("file.txt","a+");
        fprintf(fich,"%d\n",value);
        fclose(fich);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: _Style:_ The dereference operator (i.e. `*`) should _always_ abut the symbol (e.g.) `* area_square = side * side;` --> `*area_square = side * side;`

Comment: It's tremendously wasteful to do `fopen/fprintf/fclose` on _every_ write. Move `FILE *fich;` to global/file scope. Remove the `fopen` and `fclose` from `write_on_file`. Put the `fopen` at the top of `main` and the `fclose` at the bottom of `main`

Comment: Unless you're going to write the data as _binary_, you don't need separate functions, just different `fprintf` statements. so do (e.g.) `fprintf(fich,"%d\n",*area_circle);` directly. And, for strings, do `fprintf(fich,"%s\n",my_string);`

Comment: Thank you @CraigEstey! Apologies it took me so long to answer. I just added below a final answer. That is the best I could come up with. Please let me know if you think there are ways of improving it. FYI — I had to do fopen & fclose multiple times due to the switch-case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thank you @CraigEstey! Apologies it took me so long to answer. I just added below a final answer. That is the best I could come up with. Please let me know if you think there are ways of improving it.

There are a few things I'd do.

> FYI — I had to do fopen & fclose multiple times due to the switch-case.

As I mentioned in my comments, the alternative is to do the `fopen/fclose` once. Here, there's so little data being output that it's *not* an egregious error to do them for each block of data.

But, it's a lot of replicated code. Simplifying things and consolidating into a function can help.

Your program's menu has no "exit the program" option, so [I'm guessing that] you had to `ctrl-c` to break out. This could leave the output file in an indeterminate state.

Sometimes a custom `printf`-like function can help. This requires use of `stdarg.h` and the `va_*` macros--some food for [your] thought.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define PI 3.14

void square_functions(double side, double *square_perimeter, double *square_area);
void circle_functions(double radius, double *area_circle, double *circumference);

FILE *fich;

void __attribute__((__format__(__printf__,1,2)))
outf(const char *fmt,...)
{
    va_list ap;

    if (fich == NULL)
        fich = fopen("file.txt", "a+");

    va_start(ap,fmt);
    vfprintf(fich,fmt,ap);
    va_end(ap);

#if 0
    fclose(fich);
    fich = NULL;
#else
    fflush(fich);
#endif
}

int
main(void)
{

    double radius;
    double area_circle;
    double circumference;
    double side;
    double square_area;
    double square_perimeter;
    int choice;

    while (1) {
        printf("\nEnter 1 to calculate the square");
        printf("\nEnter 2 to calculate the circumference");
        printf("\nEnter your option:");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        outf("%s", "\n\nThe option chosen is: ");
        outf("%d\n", choice);

        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            printf("Please enter the side of the square: ");
            scanf("%lf", &side);

            outf("%s", "\nThe side of the square is: ");
            outf("%lf", side);

            if (side > 0) {
                square_functions(side, &square_perimeter, &square_area);
                printf("\nSquare area: %lf", square_area);
                printf("\nSquare perimeter: %lf\n", square_perimeter);
                outf("%s", "\nThe square area is: ");
                outf("%lf", square_area);
                outf("%s", "\nThe square perimeter is: ");
                outf("%lf", square_perimeter);
            }
            else {
                printf("The value is invalid, the operation has been cancelled");
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("\n\nPlease enter the radius fo the circle: ");
            scanf("%lf", &radius);

            outf("%s", "\nThe radius of the circle is: ");
            outf("%lf", radius);

            if (radius > 0) {
                circle_functions(radius, &area_circle, &circumference);
                printf("\nCircle area: %lf\n", area_circle);
                printf("\nCircumference: %lf\n", circumference);
                outf("%s", "\nThe circle area is: ");
                outf("%lf", area_circle);
                outf("%s", "\nThe circumference is: ");
                outf("%lf", circumference);
            }
            else {
                printf("The value is invalid, the operation has been cancelled");
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    if (fich != NULL)
        fclose(fich);

    return 0;
}

void
square_functions(double side, double *square_perimeter, double *square_area)
{
    *square_perimeter = side * 4;
    *square_area = side * side;
}

void
circle_functions(double radius, double *area_circle, double *circumference)
{
    *area_circle = PI * radius * radius;
    *circumference = 2 * PI * radius;
}
```

---

When we need to return *multiple* values, as you're doing, we have to pass pointers to the values we wish to return.

This is fine for one or two, but it gets messy for more than that. For example, suppose a function had to calculate (e.g.) nine values. It would be painful to pass down nine pointers.

We *could* use an array, but we'd lose the distinctiveness of the symbols (e.g. `radius` vs `circumference`).

In the general case, it can be beneficial to create a `struct` for all the values and then pass a *single* pointer for the struct.

So, here's a version that does that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define PI 3.14

typedef struct {
    double radius;
    double area_circle;
    double circumference;
    double side;
    double square_area;
    double square_perimeter;
} data_t;

void square_functions(data_t *data);
void circle_functions(data_t *data);

FILE *fich;

void __attribute__((__format__(__printf__,1,2)))
outf(const char *fmt,...)
{
    va_list ap;

    if (fich == NULL)
        fich = fopen("file.txt", "a+");

    va_start(ap,fmt);
    vfprintf(fich,fmt,ap);
    va_end(ap);
}

void
flush(void)
{

    if (fich != NULL) {
#if 0
        fclose(fich);
        fich = NULL;
#else
        fflush(fich);
#endif
    }
}

int
main(void)
{
    int choice;
    data_t data;

    choice = -1;

    while (choice != 3) {
        printf("\nEnter 1 to calculate the square");
        printf("\nEnter 2 to calculate the circumference");
        printf("\nEnter 3 to exit the program");
        printf("\nEnter your option:");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        outf("%s", "\n\nThe option chosen is: ");
        outf("%d\n", choice);

        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            printf("Please enter the side of the square: ");
            scanf("%lf", &data.side);

            outf("%s", "\nThe side of the square is: ");
            outf("%lf", data.side);

            if (data.side > 0) {
                square_functions(&data);

                printf("\nSquare area: %lf", data.square_area);
                printf("\nSquare perimeter: %lf\n", data.square_perimeter);

                outf("%s", "\nThe square area is: ");
                outf("%lf", data.square_area);
                outf("%s", "\nThe square perimeter is: ");
                outf("%lf", data.square_perimeter);
            }
            else {
                printf("The value is invalid, the operation has been cancelled");
            }

            flush();
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("\n\nPlease enter the radius fo the circle: ");
            scanf("%lf", &data.radius);

            outf("%s", "\nThe radius of the circle is: ");
            outf("%lf", data.radius);

            if (data.radius > 0) {
                circle_functions(&data);
                printf("\nCircle area: %lf\n", data.area_circle);
                printf("\nCircumference: %lf\n", data.circumference);
                outf("%s", "\nThe circle area is: ");
                outf("%lf", data.area_circle);
                outf("%s", "\nThe circumference is: ");
                outf("%lf", data.circumference);
            }
            else {
                printf("The value is invalid, the operation has been cancelled");
            }

            flush();
            break;

        case 3:
            break;

        default:
            printf("The choice is invalid\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    if (fich != NULL)
        fclose(fich);

    return 0;
}

void
square_functions(data_t *data)
{
    data->square_perimeter = data->side * 4;
    data->square_area = data->side * data->side;
}

void
circle_functions(data_t *data)
{
    data->area_circle = PI * data->radius * data->radius;
    data->circumference = 2 * PI * data->radius;
}
```

---

There's still a bunch of replicated code when doing the output of the values to both `stdout` and the file.

Another common function can consolidate that. Note that doing the uppercasing of the string in the `outval` function is a "cute" nicety--it preserves the case of your original messages. But, it could be eliminated if it were "okay" to output the same [lowercase] string to both outputs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define PI 3.14

typedef struct {
    double radius;
    double area_circle;
    double circumference;
    double side;
    double square_area;
    double square_perimeter;
} data_t;

void square_functions(data_t *data);
void circle_functions(data_t *data);

FILE *fich;

void __attribute__((__format__(__printf__,1,2)))
outf(const char *fmt,...)
{
    va_list ap;

    if (fich == NULL)
        fich = fopen("file.txt", "a+");

    va_start(ap,fmt);
    vfprintf(fich,fmt,ap);
    va_end(ap);
}

void
flush(void)
{

    if (fich != NULL) {
#if 0
        fclose(fich);
        fich = NULL;
#else
        fflush(fich);
#endif
    }
}

void
outval(const char *lostr,double val)
{
    int upflg;
    int chr;
    const char *src;
    char *dst;
    char upstr[1000];

    // convert string to upper case on first letters
    dst = upstr;
    upflg = 1;
    for (src = lostr;  *src != 0;  ++src, ++dst) {
        chr = *src;

        switch (chr) {
        case ' ':
        case '\t':
            upflg = 1;
            break;

        default:
            if (upflg)
                chr = toupper(chr);
            upflg = 0;
            break;
        }

        *dst = chr;
    }
    *dst = 0;

    printf("%s: %lf\n", upstr, val);
    outf("The %s is: %lf\n",lostr,val);
}

int
main(void)
{
    int choice;
    data_t data;

    choice = -1;

    while (choice != 3) {
        printf("\nEnter 1 to calculate the square");
        printf("\nEnter 2 to calculate the circumference");
        printf("\nEnter 3 to exit the program");
        printf("\nEnter your option:");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        outf("\n");
        outf("%s", "The option chosen is: ");
        outf("%d\n", choice);

        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            printf("Please enter the side of the square: ");
            scanf("%lf", &data.side);

            outval("side of the square",data.side);

            if (data.side > 0) {
                square_functions(&data);
                outval("square area",data.square_area);
                outval("square perimeter",data.square_perimeter);
            }
            else {
                printf("The value is invalid, the operation has been cancelled");
            }

            flush();
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("\n\nPlease enter the radius fo the circle: ");
            scanf("%lf", &data.radius);

            outval("radius of the circle",data.radius);

            if (data.radius > 0) {
                circle_functions(&data);
                outval("circle area",data.area_circle);
                outval("circumference",data.circumference);
            }
            else {
                printf("The value is invalid, the operation has been cancelled");
            }

            flush();
            break;

        case 3:
            break;

        default:
            printf("The choice is invalid\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    if (fich != NULL)
        fclose(fich);

    return 0;
}

void
square_functions(data_t *data)
{
    data->square_perimeter = data->side * 4;
    data->square_area = data->side * data->side;
}

void
circle_functions(data_t *data)
{
    data->area_circle = PI * data->radius * data->radius;
    data->circumference = 2 * PI * data->radius;
}
```

Comment: Wow @Craig Estey! Thanks so much for preparing all this code. It will definitely let me improve and gain knowledge on various fronts!! Thank you very much again!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please find below a final version of the code that works properly.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PI 3.14

void square_functions (double side, double *square_perimeter, double *square_area);
void circle_functions (double radius, double *area_circle, double *circumference);

int main() 
{ 

    double radius, area_circle, circumference, side, square_area, square_perimeter;
    int choice;
    FILE *fich;

    while (1) 
    {
    printf("\nEnter 1 to calculate the square"); 
    printf("\nEnter 2 to calculate the circumference");
    printf("\nEnter your option:"); 
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    fich = fopen("file.txt","a+");
    fprintf(fich,"%s", "\n\nThe option chosen is: ");
    fprintf(fich,"%d\n",choice);
    fclose(fich);

    switch (choice) 
        { 
        case 1:
            printf("Please enter the side of the square: ");
            scanf("%lf", &side);
            fich = fopen("file.txt","a+");
            fprintf(fich,"%s", "\nThe side of the square is: ");
            fprintf(fich,"%lf",side);
            if(side > 0)
            {
            square_functions (side, &square_perimeter, &square_area);
            printf("\nSquare area: %lf", square_area);
            printf("\nSquare perimeter: %lf\n", square_perimeter);  
            fprintf(fich,"%s", "\nThe square area is: ");
            fprintf(fich,"%lf", square_area);
            fprintf(fich,"%s", "\nThe square perimeter is: ");
            fprintf(fich,"%lf", square_perimeter);
            fclose(fich);
            }
            else
            {
            printf("The value is invalid, the operation has been cancelled");
            } 
        break;

        case 2:
            printf("\n\nPlease enter the radius fo the circle: ");
            scanf("%lf", &radius);
            fich = fopen("file.txt","a+");
            fprintf(fich,"%s", "\nThe radius of the circle is: ");
            fprintf(fich,"%lf",radius);         
            if(radius > 0)
            {
            circle_functions (radius, &area_circle, &circumference);       
            printf("\nCircle area: %lf\n", area_circle);
            printf("\nCircumference: %lf\n", circumference);
            fprintf(fich,"%s", "\nThe circle area is: ");
            fprintf(fich,"%lf",area_circle);
            fprintf(fich,"%s", "\nThe circumference is: ");
            fprintf(fich,"%lf",circumference);
            fclose(fich);
            }
            else
            {
            printf("The value is invalid, the operation has been cancelled");
            }
        break;
        }
    }
return 0;
}

void square_functions (double side, double *square_perimeter, double *square_area)
{       
        *square_perimeter = side * 4;
        *square_area = side * side;
}

void circle_functions (double radius, double *area_circle, double *circumference) 
{
        *area_circle = PI * radius * radius;
        *circumference = 2 * PI * radius;   
}
```